# Best way to structure category, subcategory and subsubcategory into multiple array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need an help to correctly structure a multiple array based on table named "products" structure like this:

```
PRODUCTS
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| id | name | category | subcategory | subsubcategory |
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | el1  |    1     |       1     |       5        |
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 2  | el2  |    2     |       3     |       1        |
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+
| 3  | el3  |    2     |       1     |                |
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

The other tables are structure like this:

```
CATEGORY

+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  cat1  |
+----+--------+
| 2  |  cat2  |
+----+--------+
| 3  |  cat3  |
+----+--------+

SUBCATEGORY

+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |  subcat1  |
+----+-----------+
| 2  |  subcat2  |
+----+-----------+
| 3  |  subcat3  |
+----+-----------+

SUBSUBCATEGORY

+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
| 1  |  subsubcat1  |
+----+--------------+
| 2  |  subsubcat2  |
+----+--------------+
| 3  |  subsubcat3  |
+----+--------------+
```

What I want to obtain is a array with all of this information easy accessibile to foreach into a page:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array(
     [id]   => 1
     [name] => cat1

     [subcategory] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
           [id]   => 1
           [name] => subcat1

           [subsubcategory] => Array(
              [0] => Array(
                 [id] => 1
                 [name] => subsubcat1

                 // products here
              )
           )
        )
     )
  )
)
```

And create a page like this:

```
<h2>CAT NAME</h2>
   <h3>SUB CAT NAME 1</h3>
       <h4>SUBSUB CAT NAME 5</h4>
            <p>PRODUCT 1</p>
            <p>PRODUCT 5</p>

<h2>CAT NAME 2</h2>
   <h3>SUB CAT NAME 2</h3>
       <p>PRODUCT 2</p>

<h2>CAT NAME 3</h2>
       <p>PRODUCT 3</p>

<h2>CAT NAME 4</h2>
   <h3>SUB CAT NAME 10</h3>
       SUBSUB CAT NAME 2
            <p>PRODUCT 4</p>
```

Comment: If there's a limitation of 1 query, try to use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Benyi unfortunately there's not. I need to insert multiple products into hierarchical structure.